# Redirect to custom 404 error page with .htaccess when the site url is unknown

Tags: .htaccess

I am using an .htaccess file to get user-friendly urls like:

mysite/about

mysite/articles/some_article
etc.

Everything works fine, but now I have to add to my .htaccess file a redirection to a custom 404-page:
mysite/error-404

For test purposes I did it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite/error-404
```

and it works both on localhost and on a "live" test site.

The problem is that I don't know what will be the site url or even if it will be in root folder or in a subfolder like

```
http://somesite/mysite
```

How can I rewrite the redirection to a 404-page to make it universal? Is it possible to get a full url of the site folder (whatever/mysite/) and to write the redirection like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 {http://whatever/mysite/}error-404
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my .htaccess file, it hides the 404 page and redirects them back to the root of the domain

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /error
RewriteRule ^error$ / [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a proceeding slash and not declare the URL at all.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error-404
```

This will always grab the page from `http://domain.com/error-404`, although the URL will remain as whatever the 404ing URL is they're trying to access.

The only thing you need to be sure of is that your 404 page is in the domain root!

Comment: The point is that all the content may be in some subfolder and not in a domain root: `http://domain.com/subdomain/error-404`, so it has to be something generic...

Comment: Actually I found another way to deal with a 404 error, but it not seems to be elegant...
I get 404 in 3 cases - wrong page, wrong content on a page, or slashes in url. So I added some code to check if a requested page or article exists in DB, and if it doesn't - I do a redirect to the custom 404-page. And in case of slash in url adding to htaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=error-404` did what I need...
Are there any other cases in which I can get a 404 error?